# Does a `BindingResolver` create objects when calling the Update method?

Tags: moryx

I am using the `BindingResolverFactory` to enable property binding in the config of my own module as described [here](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Framework/blob/dev/docs/articles/Core/Bindings.md#bindings). The bindings map to properties of an object that is created solely from the bindings that are given. for the purpose of this question let's assume I'm just setting the same string `'example'` to all the binded properties.
The type of the object that should be created using the bindings from the config looks similar to this

```cs
public class Foo {

  public string FooString { get; set; }

  public Bar FooBar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {

  public string BarString { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Start()` method of my `ModuleController`, I now create an `IBindingResolver` for all Bindings that are configured. I assume here that the two configured bindings are `FooString` and `FooBar.BarString`

```cs
// Somewhere 
var resolverFactory = new BindingResolverFactory()
var fooStringResolver = resolverFactory.Create("FooString");
var barStringResolver = resolverFactory.Create("FooBar.BarString");
```

Now I want to create an object of type `Foo`

```cs
var foo = new Foo();
fooStringResolver.Update(foo, "example")
barStringResolver.Update(foo, "example") // Can this work?
```

Can I just let the resolver take care of whether or not the `Bar` object is already created or do I need to create it first?
Since I need the `FooBar` property to be null, if non of the configured bindings refer to it, I would otherwise need to first create the object and then remove it, if its not needed, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not as this would duplicate code we already have for configs and EntrySerialize. MORYX has the DefaultValueProvider which can construct the types for you and than you populate the object tree with bindings.

To use the `DefaultValueProvider` you need to pass it to the [`ValueProviderExecutor`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Framework/blob/dev/src/Moryx/Configuration/ValueProvider/ValueProviderExecutor.cs)

```cs
var foo = new Foo();
ValueProviderExecutor.Execute(foo, new ValueProviderExecutorSettings()
  .AddProvider(new ActivatorValueProvider()));
fooStringResolver.Update(foo, "example")
barStringResolver.Update(foo, "example") // Should now work
```